# Dynamically created onClickListener and start of a new activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to add some buttons at runtime and want to assign an OnClickListener that triggers the start of a new activity.

But I get a `The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<CollectionDemoActivity>) is undefined` error in my IDE Editor.

While  `startActivity(new Intent(this,CollectionDemoActivity.class));`  is accepted from the IDE and works fine when I call it from e.g. the `onStart()` Method

But I need the buttons dynamically created..... What am I doing wrong? What is the the best alternative for this?

```
 final LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

                        Button btn = new Button(this);
                        btn.setId(i);
                        final int id_ = btn.getId();
                        btn.setText("_button " + id_);
                        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                        ll.addView(btn, params);

                        Button btn1 = ((Button) ll.findViewById(id_));
                        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                                        "Button clicked index = " + id_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(this,CollectionDemoActivity.class));
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside the anonymous `OnClickListener` refers to to exactly this surrounding class, not to the `Activity`. Assuming the Activities name is `MyActivity`, change `this` to `MyActivity.this` or `getContext()`